# API is called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have app about hockey statistics, I dont have endpoint with this stats , I have endpoint with team and player stats. I am calling api with first team , select first 2 players save to arr and call api again with another team query, find top players from another team and save it .
Than sort topPlayers and display it.
When I open console.log() => NETWORK i can see  API with specific team is called twice.
How to fix it?

```
const teamQuery = useMemo(() => {
    return [
      "NSH", "TBL", "PIT", "CHI", "VGK", "MIN", "ANA",
      "FLA", "PHI", "WSH", "ARI", "NYI", "SJS", "CGY",
      "BUF", "NYR", "CBJ", "NJD", "DET", "DAL",
      "TOR", "MTL", "BOS", "LAK", "COL", "WPG",
      "SEA", "CAR", "OTT", "EDM", "STL", "VAN"
    ];
  }, []);

  const fetchTeamData = async (teamQuery) => {
    try {
      const queryParam = encodeURIComponent(teamQuery);
      const res = await axios.get(`/api/NHL/findTeam?team=${queryParam}`);
      return res.data.data; 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return null; 
    }
  };



const fetchAllTeamsData = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoad(true);
    const topPlayers = [];

    for (const team of teamQuery) {

      setClub(team);
      const teamData = await fetchTeamData(team);

      if (teamData && teamData.players) {
        const sortedPlayers = teamData.players.sort((a, b) => b.stats.points - a.stats.points);
        const teamTopPlayers = sortedPlayers.slice(0, 2);
        topPlayers.push(...teamTopPlayers);
      }
    }

    // sort players 
    const sortedTopPlayers = topPlayers.sort((a, b) => b.stats.points - a.stats.points);
    setAllTopPlayers(sortedTopPlayers);

    const sortedTopGoals = [...topPlayers].sort((a, b) => b.stats.goals - a.stats.goals);
    setTopGoals(sortedTopGoals);

    const sortedTopAssists = [...topPlayers].sort((a, b) => b.stats.asists - a.stats.asists);
    setTopAssists(sortedTopAssists);

    const sortedMostPIM = [...topPlayers].sort((a, b) => b.stats.penalty - a.stats.penalty);
    setMostPIM(sortedMostPIM);

    setLoad(false);
  }, [teamQuery]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllTeamsData();
  }, [fetchAllTeamsData]);
```

Comment: You probably have Strict Mode enabled.

Comment: I have reactStrictMode: true in next.config.js

Comment: Everything is working properly, but I noticed in the console log, under the network tab, that the API is being called twice. Each call takes around 250ms to complete. Is this a significant issue?

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode

It‘s a feature, not a bug! This will go away in Production.